# Best Practice when opening ListView clicking on item of previous ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

what is the best practice to follow when you have an activity with many fragments ( handled by ViewPager), **one of the fragments has a listView inside and it supposed that when i click on item - opens another listView.**

Soo, should another listView be:

- **another fragment**;
- **activity**
- or in some way **"restart" current fragment using another data** that i pass to an adapter ( i don't even know if it is possible :)

I mean, on item click fragment shut downs and inside of onCreate we have something like this (sorry for pseudo-code) :

```
        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 if(...) 
 {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<...>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, Content.ITEMS_A);
 } 
 else
 {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<...>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, Content.ITEMS_B);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely be opening another `Activity` which has a `Fragment` inside.

If the new list view has a strong link to the current `Fragment`'s one then you could start that Activity from within your `Fragment`. This should only be done if the user cannot go to any other Activity from this list. If they can then you should call up to your `Fragment`'s `Activity` to start you're new `Activity`.